# Unique Count of YTD per month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a YTD count for each of unique employees who have had any revenue in the current or preceding months

**Table1**

```
Month       Employee    Revenue
01-04-18    A           867
01-04-18    B   
01-04-18    C   
01-04-18    D   
01-05-18    A           881
01-05-18    B   
01-05-18    C           712
01-05-18    D   
01-06-18    A           529
01-06-18    B           456
01-06-18    C   
01-06-18    D           878
```

**Expected Output**

```
Month       Count
01-04-18    1
01-05-18    2
01-06-18    4
```

In the 1st month only **A** had any revenue so the count is 1, in the 2nd month **A & C** had revenue till date so the count is 2 and finally in the 3rd month **A, B, C & D** have had revenue in the current or preceding months (**C** had revenue in month 2 but not month 3) so the count is 4.

Is there any way to get this result?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, because you have an aggregation and a window function.  I would go for the approach of marking the first month where a use has revenue and then using that information:

```
select month,
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 and revenue is not null then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by month)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee order by (case when revenue is not null then month end) nulls last) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by month;
```

The `row_number()` is enumerating the months for each employee putting the ones with revenue first.  So, if there is a month with revenue, it goes first.

The outer aggregation then does a cumulative sum check both for the sequence and whether the revenue is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a slightly different approach, still using an aggregate of an analytic function inside an inline view, but sticking to `count()` as I think the intent is slightly cleaeer:

```
select month,
  count(has_revenue) as result
from (
  select month, employee,
    case when count(revenue)
      over (partition by employee order by month) > 0
        then employee end as has_revenue
  from table1
)
group by month
```

For the inline view, the analytic count for each month/employee uses the default window of unbounded preceding to current row, so it ignore any rows in future months; and only gives a not-null response if that count is non-zero. The outer count ignore nulls in that generated column expression.

Demo with your sample data in a CTE:

```
with table1 (month, employee, revenue) as (
            select date '2018-04-01', 'A', 867 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 'B', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 'C', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 'D', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 'A', 881 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 'B', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 'C', 712 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 'D', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-06-01', 'A', 529 from dual
  union all select date '2018-06-01', 'B', 456 from dual
  union all select date '2018-06-01', 'C', null from dual
  union all select date '2018-06-01', 'D', 878 from dual
)
select month,
  count(has_revenue) as result
from (
  select month, employee,
    case when count(revenue)
      over (partition by employee order by month) > 0
        then employee end as has_revenue
  from table1
)
group by month
order by month;

MONTH          RESULT
---------- ----------
2018-04-01          1
2018-05-01          2
2018-06-01          4
```

This is cumulative over all rows in your data set, but you only showed data from one year. If your data has multiple years, and you aren't filtering to a single year already, then add the year into the partitioning:

```
  select month, employee,
    case when count(revenue)
      over (partition by employee, trunc(month, 'YYYY') order by month) > 0
        then employee end as has_revenue
  from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd use a compound table expression to pull the distinct months from your table, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT` to count the distinct employees, using the appropriate join criteria. Or, in other words:

```
WITH cteMonths AS (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH
                     FROM TABLE1)
SELECT m.MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.EMPLOYEE)
  FROM cteMonths m
  INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1
    ON t1.MONTH <= m.MONTH AND
       t1.REVENUE IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY m.MONTH
  ORDER BY m.MONTH;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f420/1)

Best of luck.